# Unicode for currency not showing the currency symbol

Tags: java, unicode, textpad

I have this code

```
     String [] currency = {"US Dollar", "Philippine Peso", "British Pound", "Japanese Yen", "Indian Rupee",
                                    "Syrian Pound"};
   char [] symbol = { '\u0024', '\u20B1', '\u00A3','\u00A5', '\u20AC'};
```

I want the output to have this format:
this is in a for loop:

```
System.out.println("\t\t"+ currency[i] + " ======> "+ symbol[i] + sell[i]
```

I want the output to show the currency symbol, but it is showing different characters.
please help

Comment: For me its showing correct output though$
?
£
¥
€

Comment: It showed the correct values except for "Peso" with cp1252 encoding. Change your console's encoding to UTF-8 and you should be good.

Comment: wait..How to change the console to UTF-8?

Comment: If you are trying it in a command prompt, use `chcp 65001`. In eclipse, you can change it from Run Configurations-> Common->Console Encoding. It is default cp1252. Change it to UTF-8

Comment: I am using textpad. I am using a command prompt. Can you tell me the steps please?

Comment: You could start your program with `java MainClass > output.txt` and take a look at output.txt with a hex editor to verify that your Java program is correct and that your issues are related to the terminal.